# Fluent NHibernate: How do you change the underlying sql type for an automapped collection of strings?

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008, fluent, automapping, backing-field

I have a class:

```
public class ParentClass
{
     //other stuff
     IList<string> ChildPages
}
```

When '`IList<string> ChildPages`' gets **automapped** by **Fluent NHibernate** a '`ChildPages`' join table is created with a `nvarchar(255)` backing field for each string in the collection.

But the problem is that I want the sql backing field to be '`text`', so that I can have lengthy entries for this entity.

What's the easiest way to make this change?

How do you change the underlying type of automapped primitive collections?

Also, for extra points, how would you do this with a convention or mapping overrides?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an override convention so that strings use `text` instead of `nvarchar2 (255)`, as shown in the solution [**on this other thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712668/how-to-fine-tune-fluentnhibernates-auto-mapper). If you only want such behavior for a specific property, something like this in your fluent configuration would work:

```
AutoMap
    .AssemblyOf<ParentClass>()
    .Override<ChildPage>(map =>
        {
            mapping.Map(x => x.Page).CustomType("StringClob").CustomSqlType("text");
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this will work because 'ChildPages' is a property name rather than a type.